# Twig Add Filter

Tags: zend-framework2, twig

I have a use-case for adding a `ucfirst` filter in my twig template and I have it working just fine by using this:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()
     ->get('Twig_Environment')
     ->addFilter(
         new \Twig_SimpleFilter(
             'ucfirst',
             'ucfirst'
         )
     );
```

However I am curious if it's possible to add this filter via the `module.config.php`?

Perhaps something like this:

```
'zfctwig'         => [
    'environment_options' => [
        'cache' => 'data/cache/twig',
        'debug' => true
    ],
    'extensions'          => [
        'Twig_Extension_Debug'
    ],
    'Twig_Environment' => [
        'filters' => [
            'ucfirst' => 'ucfirst'
        ]
    ]
]
```

I know this snippet is wrong, but if it is possible, what would the configuration look like?

I'm currently using ZF2 with the [ZfcTwig](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcTwig) module.

Comment: Why you don't use the [capitalize](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/capitalize.html#capitalize) twig filter?

Comment: Because it sets the rest of the string to lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, it's not possible to register new filter just with configuration in ZfcTwig module.

But it is recommended to create project extension ([twig doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#creating-an-extension)) and put all your project specific filters (tags, tests, etc) there.

Example of this project extension:

```php
<?php

namespace Application\Twig;

use Twig_Extension;
use Twig_SimpleFilter;

class ApplicationExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [
            new Twig_SimpleFilter('ucfirst', 'ucfirst'),
        ];
    }

    public function getTests()
    {
        return [
            // ...
        ];
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            // ...
        ];
    }
}
```

and then you can just register this extension to the ZfcTwig configuration:

```php
'zfctwig' => [
    'extensions' => [
        \Application\Twig\ApplicationExtension::class,
    ],
]
```

If you need then add some another filter or function, you can simply add it to this extension and start using it.

Comment: That's a good idea. I was trying to find a way where I had a central location instead of putting what I am using now in each of the Controllers where it's used in that particular view. This appears to do what I was looking for just a different approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in multi-pages and non dynamic as it seems recommended, or the simple way:

```
$twig_env->addFilter(new \Twig\TwigFilter('ucf','ucfirst'));
```

No need to edit YAML files, non php stuff or use composer.